# which is better? JMF or VLCJ. especially for streaming youtube videos

Tags: java, jmf, libvlc, vlcj

I am an average java developer and i am trying to come up with a browser that is developed entirely in java. I want that my browser must be able to play youtube videos, and for that i was planning to use JMF. 
Here are my questions:

1) can JMF be used to stream and play videos from links like youtube. If yes, can Some one please point to a demo link(a basic one will do, rest i will develop)

2) If that is possible, should we use JMF or VLCJ? If you recommend VLCJ, where can i find "libvlc"? I had a hard time looking for it.

Thanks to everyone for their help in advance

Answer (score 7):

JMF seems to be abandoned, so VLCJ is a better choice

you can find libvlc.dll [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/1.1.7/win32/) . Pick the biggest. Or just install VLC player.

Comment: If you have long time running videos, you may encounter crashes with vlcj - check this thread also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768397/how-to-control-vlc-by-java

Answer (score 3):

JMF is quite obsolete right now. It's so old that its player won't open any of the video files used nowadays and if you're trying to capture webcam video you won't be able to detect your camera if you're running on Windows 7.

I heard Xuggler is fine but I really couldn't get it to work after trying hard for a few days so I would recommend VLCJ, which works great and its really easy to set up.

The libraries used in VLCJ are included in VideoLAN's folders when installing VLC. Just install VLC's last version and go to C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/ and there you'll find both libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll

Answer (score 1):

VLCj will play Youtube videos easily, JMF won't and is long dead - I wouldn't touch it for any new projects personally. If you're going down the VLCj route though you'll want to [look at out of process players](http://berry120.blogspot.com/2011/07/using-vlcj-for-video-reliably-with-out.html), you can't reliably include multiple players in process.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do youtube with JMF. Also check out Xuggler