# Creating a video stream with java

Tags: java, video-streaming, rtsp

This is purely of academic interest but is it possible to create a streaming video file with java. For the purpose of understanding my question, say I wanted to create a video stream which solely displayed the time. My research has only dug up using gui elements and screen grabbing with FFMpeg which is not really a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream video in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574143/stream-video-in-java)

Comment: @ToddSewell hardly even related, I want to create a stream from scratch NOT manipulate streams

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244861/live-video-streaming-using-java) has something useful?